# Sakai 11.3 Build in Virtual Box What is the gateway?

Tags: maven, tomcat, sakai

Environment: Linux, Ubuntu 16.04, Maven 3.3.9, Tomcat 8.0.32, Java 1.8.

I followed this [guide](https://confluence.sakaiproject.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=106792022#Sakai11installguide(source)-2.0GettheSakaisourcecode):

Everything seemed to download just fine but now when it comes to the gateway address, it was not given in the guide. my localhost:8080 goes straight to tomcat. localhost:8080/sakai gives a 404 and localhost:8080/portal gives a 404

Comment: The guide tells you to do a lot more than 'download'. Did you perform each step? It appears Sakai isn't installed in Tomcat.

Answer (score 0):

`localhost:8080/portal` should give you Sakai's home page.

The guide tells you to do a lot more than just download. Did you perform each step? It appears step 4.0 hasn't been executed, or has been executed incorrectly.